# Testing a scenario with multiple I/O data in BDD (Squish)/Data driven testing in BDD format

Tags: bdd, squish

Following is the sample project I am working on.

Scenario :Adder application to be tested in BDD.

Given
      Adder application is running
When 
     Two input values are given corresponding to which we get an output.
Then 
      Validate the output field.

I am, able to execute the test with a set of 2 input values.

Is it possible to execute the same scenario with the different set of input values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible. The solution is called `Scenario Outline`
F.e.

```
Scenario Outline: Adder application to be tested in BDD.
Given Adder application is running 
When <input_values> are given corresponding to which we get an output. 
Then Validate the <output> field.      

Examples:
| input_values | output  |
| foo          | bar     |
| new foo      | new bar |
```

For more info check [squish documention link](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/tutorials-qt.html#tut-bdd-qt-scenario-outline)

Comment: Hi Igor ,thank you so much.This worked for me but I am facing a small issue,the GIVEN part is  executed for every value that is specified in the example ie the application is getting launched again and again.Whereas I want the application to be launched only once ".Any solution ?

Comment: hm, as a quick solution you can move your step of loading application to the background part. Try `Background:
  Given Adder application is running` see https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#background But: 1) I am not sure that this feature is able in squish. 2) background steps will run before every scenario

Comment: Hey, the Background tag didn't work.I then  tried mentioning the statement startApplication("Add.jar") in my BDD_hook file.                                               OnFeatureStart(function(context) {
    startApplication("Add.jar");
   });...In this case as the feature is executed just once hence the application is also launched once with the feature and not on every scenario call.

Comment: Well, then congrats - you found the solution:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for every scenario, use the OnScenarioStart hook...

You can also do this without a Scenario Outline, using table data:

```
Scenario: Adder application to be tested in BDD.
Given Adder application is running 
Then for each input value provided, verify the output value.
    | inputvalue | outputvalue |
    | foo | bar |
    | new foo | new bar |
```

You access the table in your step using the context.table object

```
Then("for each input value provided, verify the output value", function(context) {
    var table = context.table;

    // Skip initial row with column headers by starting at index 1
    for (var i = 1; i < table.length; ++i) {
        var inputValue = table[i][0];
        var outputValue = table[i][1];
        // make magic happen
    }
});
```